# Need full highchart bars between months

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I have created High chart to full fill my requirement as shown in attached Image and i have tried below code in fiddle
example code in fiddle is as follows

https://jsfiddle.net/vsLr07ak/

Below is my code

```
   Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
    type: 'column'
 },
 title: {
    text: 'HISTORICAL NEWS SENTIMENT'
 },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
     labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
    min: -100,
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 10,
    showLastdataLabel: true,
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['26. Nov', '24. Dec', '21. Jan', '18. Feb', '18. March']
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: null,
    data: [15, 13, 14, 17, 12]

     }, {
    name: null,
    data: [12, -12, -13, 21, 11]
  }]
  });
```

Html code is as

```
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">. 
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

but it display 2 bar for per month, I want it show as below attached image.

Can any one help me out?

and I want my chart as shown in image [image: chart image]

Comment: "nothing work for me" does not seem a good problem description.

Comment: @bradbury9 I mean to say that i have tried but not able to generate the chart as displaying in image

Comment: Hi @Xtremcool, Do you want to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bgj85L9c/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `category`, you should use `datetime` xAxis type and define `x` values as timestamps:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    data: [
        [17227780000, 15],
        [18523780000, 13],
        [19819780000, 14],
        [21115780000, 17],
        [22411780000, 12],
        [23707780000, 12],
        [25003780000, -12],
        [26299780000, -13],
        [27595780000, 21],
        [28891780000, 11]
    ]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/83us07cx/

or use `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties:

```
series: [{
    pointStart: 17227780000,
    pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15, // 15 days
    name: null,
    color: 'red',
    negativeColor: 'blue',
    data: [15, 13, 14, 17, 12, 12, -12, -13, 21, 11]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sqtha8xm/

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointStart

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.negativeColor

Comment: can you see the image which i had posted in question?

Comment: @Xtremcool, Sure, in my example the columns are located between months as you wanted.

Comment: I want multiple bars between the months as shown in image, I don't know how to get that, as I am trying to generate graph as shown i question. Also I m trying this for 1st time

Comment: So you need to add another series with negative values and disable `grouping`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vcwyahdt/

Comment: that I know that how to display negative values in code, for that You can review my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vsLr07ak/, but my main question is that how can I add multiple bars/line between AUG 70 to SEP 70 , As in my question please review my image screenshot it is showing more than 60 bars between 26 Nov to 24 Dec. So my question is that how can I do so?

Comment: Hi @Xtremcool, I have already answered this question - you should adjust `pointInterval` property or use proper `x` values. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t17ya0d2/ with more data.

Comment: Hey thanks, now how can I set X-axis date as define in question image, and how can I define red dotted line?

Comment: To define the labels on `xAxis` you can use `tickPositions` property and `labels.formatter` function. To add the line, you can use additional seires with `line` type and `'ShortDot'` or `'Dot'` `dashStyle`. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zhyeLmdf/